# Support for `{where: 'raw query'}` has been removed

Tags: javascript, lambda, sequelize.js, graphql, serverless-framework

I'm running a GraphQL server using the serverless framework on AWS Lambda.
I'm fetching the data in the UI using `apollo-link-batch-http`.

If I run it locally using `serverless-offline`, it works fine. But if I run it on AWS Lambda, it successfully resolves the `fooResolver` but not the `barResolver` as it throws the above error message.

The `Model.cached(300)` is a tiny cache wrapper I made. You can see it here:
https://gist.github.com/lookapanda/4676083186849bb6c5ae6f6230ad7d8f
It basically just makes me able to use my own `findById` function and so on.

The weird thing is, this error only appears, if I use `apollo-link-batch-http` but not if I use `apollo-link-http`. So if the request is batched into a single GraphQL request, there is no such errors (although, then I get this error: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9242)

I really don't know what is going on there, there is no raw where query in any of those resolvers. And it gets even weirder: It only happens with the cached result. The first request is totally valid and successful, but then every consecutive request fails with the above error message.

I really hope someone can help me, I'm getting insane :D

```js
export const fooResolver = async () => {
  const Model = db.getDB().sequelize.models.fooModel;
  const data = await Model.cached(300).findAll({
      where: {
          time: {
              [Op.gt]: Model.sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()'),
          },
          enabled: true,
          state: 'PLANNED',
      },
      order: [['time', 'DESC']],
      limit: 5,
  });
  return data.value;
};

export const barResolver = async () => {
  const models = db.getDB().sequelize.models;
  const Model = models.fooModel;
  const data = await Model.findById(data.id, {
    include: [
      {
        model: models.barModel,
        include: [
          {
            association: 'fooAssociation',
            include: [{ association: 'barAssociation' }],
            order: ['showOrder', 'ASC'],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  });

  return {
    data,
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so after tedious debugging I found out that in the cacheable wrapper I was using this snippet:
https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2325#issuecomment-366060303

I don't really know still, why exactly this error only showed up on Lambda and not locally, but it stopped erroring when I only used the `selectQuery()` method and only returned that instead of the whole `Model.addHook` stuff and so on. So basically changed this

```js
export const getSqlFromSelect = (Model, method, args) => {
  if (!SUPPORTED_SELECT_METHODS.includes(method)) {
    throw new Error('Unsupported method.');
  }

  const id = generateRandomHash(10);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Model.addHook('beforeFindAfterOptions', id, options, => {
      Model.removeHook('beforeFindAfterOptions', id);

      resolve(
        Model.sequelize.dialect.QueryGenerator.selectQuery(
          Model.getTableName(),
          options,
          Model
        ).slice(0, -1)
      );
    });

    return Model[method](...args).catch(reject);
  });
};
```

to this

```js
export const getSqlFromSelect = (Model, identifier, options) => {
  if (typeof identifier === 'number' || typeof identifier === 'string' || Buffer.isBuffer(identifier) {
    options.where = {
      [Model.primaryKeyAttribute]: identifier,
    };
  };

  return Model.sequelize.dialect.QueryGenerator.selectQuery(
    Model.getTableName(),
    options,
    Model
  ).slice(0, -1);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar situation, except in my case using the code below works well:

```
.findAll({
    where: {
        title: req.params.title 
    } 
})
```

Comment: Wroked for me too thanks !