# error("Support for `{where: 'raw query'}` has been removed")

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

My filtration is not working because of this error.
I did this a year ago, and all was working, but when i opened project now, and tried to start, something find error, and is not working
Here is my code:

```
async getAll(req, res) {
        const { descriptionId, locationId } = req.query
        let photos
        if (!descriptionId && !locationId) {
            photos = await Photo.findAll()
        }
        if (descriptionId && !locationId) {
            photos = await Photo.findAll({ where: descriptionId })
        }
        if (!descriptionId && locationId) {
            photos = await Photo.findAll({ where: locationId })
        }
        if (descriptionId && locationId) {
            photos = await Photo.findAll({
                where: { descriptionId, locationId },
            })
        }
        return res.json(photos)
    }
```

And I have a mistake error in title. What can i do, to never see this error again?

I tried to find information in the internet, but without success. Thank's to u, that u readed this message and for you help!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Support for \`{where: 'raw query'}\` has been removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49677774/support-for-where-raw-query-has-been-removed)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 async getAll(req, res) {
    const { descriptionId, locationId } = req.query
    let photos
    if (!descriptionId && !locationId) {
        photos = await Photo.findAll()
    }
    if (descriptionId && !locationId) {
        photos = await Photo.findAll({ where:{descriptionId} })
    }
    if (!descriptionId && locationId) {
        photos = await Photo.findAll({ where: {locationId} })
    }
    if (descriptionId && locationId) {
        photos = await Photo.findAll({
            where: { descriptionId, locationId },
        })
    }
    return res.json(photos)
}
```